# mongos can't write to replica set config server (CSRS) (invalid write concern)

Tags: mongodb, sharding, mongodb-replica-set

I'm setting up a sharded mongodb, largely per https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/. When I start the `mongos` instance, I get a stream of errors along the lines of

```
getLastError command failed: w: 'majority' is the only valid write concern
when writing to config server replica sets, got: { w: 1, wtimeout: 0 }
```

I believe this is because a config server replica set requires a `{w:majority}` write concern but for reasons unclear `mongos` is generating writes with `{w:1}`. Have looked everywhere and found no answers; the closest thing I've seen is https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-20945 but that's in the version I'm running so doesn't seem to be the answer.

Because the config server is essentially un-writeable, that prevents creating the shards and so forth, rendering the whole thing inoperable.

It's `mongos` v 2.6.12 and `mongo` v 3.2.6.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please connect to a config server, issue an `rs.status()` and add the result to your answer by [editing it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37604413/edit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-24385, the issue here is the difference in version between `mongos` and `mongod`. The earlier `mongos` version doesn't play well with the newer `mongod` due to changes in how config servers work. So the answer is, don't mix (major) versions of the two.